# Android Studio: how to remove/update the "Created by" comment added to all new classes?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

By default Android Studio automatically adds a header comment to all new classes, e.g.

```
/**
 * Created by Dan on 11/20/13.
 */
```

Where is the setting to customize or remove it?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

From the menu bar:

- on Mac OS choose `Android Studio` -> `Preferences`
- on Windows and Linux choose `File` -> `Settings`

Then look for `Editor` -> `File and Code Templates` in the left hand pane.

You have two ways you can change this...

1) Select the `Includes` tab and edit the `Created by...` text directly.

[image]

2) Select the `Templates` tab and edit the `#parse("File Header.java")` line for any template that you desire.

[image: templates tab edit]

Personally I followed option 1) and made the default header comment a TODO, e.g.

```
/**
 * TODO: Add a class header comment!
 */
```

These instructions are based on Android Studio v0.3.7. and also tested on v1.2.1.1

Comment: In my Android Studio 0.3.2 - i found the **File and Code Templates** under **File -> Settings**

Comment: And where can I change the user name?

Comment: In case you want to remove existing comments, you can use this Regex with **Edit -> Find -> Replace in Path...**: `/\*\*\n \* Created by .*\n \*/`

Comment: Any idea how to apply this template to existing files? Thanks!

Comment: In Studio (v 1.2.1.1 , Mac OS X), the changes to file header not saved to disk, every time I restart it resets, anybody observed this?

Comment: Thank you buddy, worked very well. My comments now look like this: ** /**
 * If there is no bug, then it was created by ${USER} on ${DATE},
 * otherwise, I do not know who created this f...... buggy s..t. :D
 */ **

Comment: @nerdinand put that in an answer please, and have my upvote!

Answer (score 78):

You can overwrite the ${USER} variable in the template file with the #set( $VARIABLE = "value") function.

`On windows: Press Ctrl+Alt+S and go to Settings -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header`

```
On Mac: Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> 
File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header
```

prepend the #set() function call, for example:

```
#set( $USER = "YourName" )
/**
* Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
*/
```

Answer (score 25):

As well as Dan's answer (which is the much more rigorous way), you can also click into the header, and option-enter (on Mac), and you can choose to edit the default file template. Alternatively, click the little lightbulb to get here as well

[image]

Answer (score 22):

### Change Android Studio File Header Template

**Step 1:** First hover over the **File Header** and get the yellow lightbulb and the menu out of it by clicking on it as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: yellow lightbulb menu > Edit template]

**Step 2:** Then click on the **Edit template** menu item and get the following pop-up window:

[image: Edit File Template pop-up window]

**Note:** In its Description area there are many other available Template variables, you can use them too.

**Step 3:** In the editor area add your name as shown in the following screenshot and click **"OK"** button and the current file and the future new class file headers will be generated accordingly.

[image: Updated header template configuration]

Hope this answer will be helpful to somebody else out there! :-) Cheers!
(This works on Android Studio 2.2 (September, 2015) version.)

Answer (score 10):

1. Press ctrl+shift+A
2. Type : File and Code Templates.
3. Look for File Header under Includes
4. You can type something like below

[image]

Comment: But how to include this in existing Java files, where there is no File Header included?

Answer (score 10):

### Accepted answer had instructions for Android Studio v0.3. so I decide to add instructions for Android Studio 3.0.1

- **Go to Android Studio `Preferences-> CopyRight->CopyRightProfiles` and click on [+] to add a new profile or edit existing profile.**

[image]

- **Create or update copyright template, a sample template can be copied from below:**

> Creator: Hitesh Sahu on $today
>       Last modified: $file.lastModified
>       Copyright: All rights reserved Ⓒ $today.year http://hiteshsahu.com
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file    except in compliance with the License.
>   You may obtain a copy of the License at
>       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS"
>   BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and limitations under the License.

[image]

- **Now select that newly created copyright as your default copyright profile**

  [image]
- **Lastly update copyright of entire project like below**

  [image]

Answer (score 6):

In case you want to remove all comments which have already been created. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the *Replace in path* dialog. Check the Regex option and replace

```
/\*\*\n \* Created by .*\n \*/
```

with *nothing*.

---

<sub>The regex was originally posted by nerdinand as comment to the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20109692/1788806). Although I asked him, he didn't create an answer for several months. That is why I did now, so people can find this more easily.</sub>

Comment: This is a good one. It doesn't remove those that have is as a part of the whole, though.

Comment: @androiddeveloper what do you mean? pls give an example

Comment: I mean that if the JavaDocs have more than "created by", it skips them.

Comment: @androiddeveloper This was never supposed to remove JavaDoc comments, only the "created by" comment from the top of the file (as the OP asks for). :)

Comment: I mean the same thing. You can add there more text than the "created by" part.

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable the warning as well. For me the default template was ok but seeing yellow highlighted class javadoc was annoying me. So to disable it go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> General -> Uncheck "Default File Template Usage".

You can also do it accross all projects. Just change the Project profile to Default in the same Inspections tab.

Answer (score 2):

> Settings->Editor->Copyright->Copyright Profiles

is another place (apart from "Settings->Editor->File and Code Templates") where similar template could be defined and also triggered whenever file is created.

Answer (score 2):

These steps are for `Mac` devices.

Version information used:

> Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

- `Android Studio` -> `Settings`
- `Settings` -> `File and Code Templates`
- `File and Code Templates` -> `Includes`
- `Includes` -> `File Header`

[image]

After making the adjustments, it will be displayed like this.

[image]