# Android Studio copyright statement in every project

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently imported a project from Nordic SemiConductor, and now ANY project that I create from scratch has it's copyright statement in every single file:

> /*
>    * Copyright (c) 2015, Nordic Semiconductor
>    .........................................
>    */

I went to File > Settings and checked the Copyright statements... nothing. Says it's default settings.

Then I went to File > Other Settings > Default Settings and the settings are: no Copyright statement.

I'm absolutely lost at how I can rid my projects of this statement, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see whether the above copyright statement was perhaps added to the defual file template? Go to `File --> Settings --> File and Code Templates`. Then check under the `File Headers` tab to see whether the copyright statement was added there. Alternatively you can also look under class templates. You can find more information here: [Android Studio: how to remove/update the "Created by" comment added to all new classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109203/android-studio-how-to-remove-update-the-created-by-comment-added-to-all-new-c)

Comment: I've tried that, and I don't see it there as well :(