# Change ALL file headers

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

So I know how to change the default file header in Android Studio ([Android Studio: how to remove/update the "Created by" comment added to all new classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109203/android-studio-how-to-remove-update-the-created-by-comment-added-to-all-new-c)), and can apply the default to a single class (shown in the picture there). I was wondering if there were an "apply to all" sort of button, where I would be able to change the headers of all the files in my project. I've got a lot of files, and don't really want to go through all of them and change the header.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it out, I think!
So what you do is you go to the more options by pressing right arrow and click "Run Inspection on..."
[image]

Then, click "whole project" and run the inspection. You'll get a table that looks like this:

[image]

Turns out you can just spam the link circled in red, and it'll replace all the headers!
Not sure if this is the way to do it, but this worked for me.