# Android Studio: How to update all project classes with new template?

Tags: java, android-studio

I've changed the author file header that is included in all classes to this:

```
/**
 * Author: ${USER} 
 * Email: ${EMAIL}
 */
```

But this change is not applied in the previous created classes, so how can I apply it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Your best bet is probably using control + shift + R to replace the old template.

Comment: Too bad it's not possible, it would be a lot simpler.. But thanks for answering anyway :) @Zar

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109203/android-studio-how-to-remove-update-the-created-by-comment-added-to-all-new-c